# Issues passing Edit text into an If statement

Tags: android

I have a quiz app that should contains the following: 
1- radio groups/buttons 
2- checkbox
3- editText

all should calculate a score.  I manage to get the radio groups, checkbox to work and calculate the score. however having problems with the editText

I am trying to compare the value of what's in name2 variable but I am unable to do so. I've implemented the .equals syntax but it's not working accordingly.

Any suggestions/solutions are grateful.

```
public class Quiz extends AppCompatActivity {
int score = 0;
String name;
String name2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

}

public void onRadioButtonCliked(View view) {

    Boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.yes_radio_buttonG1B3:
            if (checked)
                score++;
            break;
        case R.id.yes_radio_buttonG2B2:
            if (checked)
                score++;
            break;
        case R.id.yes_radio_buttonG3B2:
            score++;
            if (checked)
                break;
        case R.id.yes_radio_buttonG4B1:
            if (checked)
                score++;
            break;
        case R.id.yes_radio_buttonG5B2:
            if (checked)
                score++;
            break;
        case R.id.yes_radio_buttonG6B3:
            if (checked)
                score++;
            break;
    }
}


public void onCheckBoxCliked(View view) {

    Boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    CheckBox cB1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    CheckBox cB2 = (CheckBox) findViewById((R.id.checkBox2));
    CheckBox cB3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

    if (cB1.isChecked() && cB2.isChecked() && !cB3.isChecked()) {
        score++;
    }


}

public void EditText(View view) {
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    name2 = text.getText().toString();

    if (name2.equals("8")) {
        score++;

    }
}


public void submitOrder(View view) {
    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    name = username.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Thank you " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Toast.makeText(this, "You have got 8/" + score, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: since you are doing score++ which indicates that you should use integer instead of string variables. Therefore, convert your name2 from String to int and use name2.equals(8) and see the response

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a string variable, you must use "" to indicate it's a string.
Whole number are only applicable for int variable type.

```
if(name2.equals("8")){
    score++;
}
```

Comment: try name2 == "8" and see if that makes a difference (which i don't think it should). If not, you might want to share the rest of your code.

Comment: @Nero You should know that `==` does not work with Strings in Java.

Comment: Yeah, Daniel is correct, == will only compare the references, not the value itself. Lujain, please share the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the 8 with "8" as you are supposed to be comparing a String, not an integer.

Comment: Then use the debugger to check the actual value of name2

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in a comment and in the two other answers, you can't compare a String to a number.

Instead of checking a String, convert that string to an integer(assuming it is a valid int) and compare the ints instead.

First, convert:

```
int value;
try{
    value = Integer.parseInt(name2);//throws an exception if it isn't a valid integer or if name == null
}catch(Exception e){
    return;//not valid, don't continue
}
```

Then compare:

```
if(value == 8){
    score++;
}
```